# Complex vector ${x} := \Re\{{x}\} + i\Im\{{x}\}$, any relationship between $\|{x}\|_\infty$ and $\|\Re\{x\}\|_\infty$ & $\|\Im\{x\}\|_\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

For a given complex-valued vector $\mathbf{x} := \Re\{\mathbf{x}\} + i\Im\{\mathbf{x}\}$, where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

> Is there any relationship between the infinite norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty $ and the infinite norm of individual real and imaginary components, i.e., $\|\Re\{\mathbf{x}\}\|_\infty$ and $\|\Im\{\mathbf{x}\}\|_\infty$?

Comment: When you say "complex-valued" I assume you mean "$\mathbb{C}^n$-valued," where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Also, when you write $\|\textbf{x}\|_\infty$, I assume you mean the sup-norm as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, needs clarification.  I would assume $\|x\|_\infty$ means the sup norm, where the components are the absolute values of the components of $x$.

Comment: Yes, agreed with GEdgar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|\Re\{x\}\|_{\infty} \leq \|x\|_{\infty}$, $\|\Im\{x\}\|_{\infty} \leq \|x\|_{\infty}$,  and $\|x\|_{\infty} \leq \|\Re\{x\}\|_{\infty}+\|\Im\{x\}\|_{\infty} $.

[ Let $x_k=a_k+ib_k$, $1\leq k \leq n$ where $a_k,b_k \in \mathbb R$. Then  $$\|\{x\}\|_{\infty} =\max \{|x_k|:1\leq k \leq n\}$$ $$ =\max \{|a_k+ib_k|:1\leq k \leq n\} \geq \max \{|a_k|:1\leq k \leq n\}=\|\Re\{x\}\|_{\infty}$$ where I have used the fact that $|a+ib| \geq |a|$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Second inequality is similar. For the last inequality use the fact that $|a+ib| \leq |a|+|b|$].

Comment: Can we prove these relationships?

Comment: @learning I have edited my answer.